# Why I can't see Magento connect and Magento connect manager in the admin page?

Tags: magento, magento2.1

I just finished installing Magento 2.1, and I want to install a theme (template). But I cannot see Magento connect and Magento connect manager to install template. I was searching on Google and YouTube but only found results for old versions of Magento.

See the image:

[image]

Comment: it might be not installed properly and some folders are missing there plz check and reinstall it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento connect and connect manager are used to install the extension in magneto 1.

But in Magento 2, the extensions can be installed from System -> Web setup wizard.

Here is a [nice tutorial](http://magefan.com/blog/how-to-install-magento-2-extension-2/) that will help you out.

You can also enable an extension in magento 2 through cmd prompt by following below steps :

Step 1: Download/purchase the extension

Step 2: Unzip the file in a temporary directory

Step 3: Upload it to your Magento installation root directory

Step 4: Disable the cache under System­ >> Cache Management

Step 5: Enter the following at the command line, from the root folder of magento installation:

```
php ­-f bin/magento setup:upgrade
```